# Group users in Firebase RTDB

Tags: qt, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, qt5

I am using Firebase in my Qt app for Authentication and Realtime Database features, when users register they need to be assigned into the selected groups then departments of that group. Each group will have admin(s), who can access the entire group database, but the users will only access their department.

Below is my code for my registration form which assigns certain user values, how would i go about grouping the users in the database with additional options on my registration form?

```
onUserRegistered: { 

        indicator.stopAnimating()

        console.debug("User login " + success + " - " + message)

        if(success) {
            loginDialog.title = "Success!"
            firebaseDb.setUserValue("Firstname", firstname.text)
            firebaseDb.setUserValue("Surname", surname.text)
        } else {
            loginDialog.title = "An Issue occured!"
        }
        loginDialog.text = message
        loginbutton.visible = true
        registerCheckbox.visible = true
        loginDialog.open()

    }
```

I would like my database to be laid out as below, if this is appropriate for use? Multiple location groups with users within to access thier part of the database!

```
{
  "groups" : {
    "Colchester" : {
    },
    "Ipswich" : {
    },
    "CanaryWharf" : {
      "Departments" : {
        "Admin" : {
          "members" : {
            "user1" : true
          }
        },
        "Assistant" : {
          "members" : {
            "user2" : true
          }
        },
        "Reception" : {
          "members" : {
            "user3" : true,
            "user1" : true
          }
        },
        "Stylist" : {
          "members" : {
            "user4" : true
          }
        },
        "Technician" : {
          "members" : {
            "user5" : true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: There's not enough information here to answer: what group/department should each user become a member of? I.e. how can we know what group/department a specific user that fills out this form is in?

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen I did not want to over load with information, allow me to expand. The apps purpose is absence management, for business. So each user would select thier group(store/business ect) and what department they are in within that, to then view their departments calendar. and Request/Save dates of absence!

Comment: Thanks. That helps understand context. I'm just not clear what you're asking? Are you looking for help in determining your data model (which is notoriously hard)? If so, show your current model (you can get the JSON from the database by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data), show what your considering to use, and what your concerns are.

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen . I have 0 experience with Firebase, so more than anything I was looking for some advice on how to start this! I know its a really unhelpful question haha! without the use of Cloud Firestore i was wondering how to apply subcollections into Firebase Database!

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have edited my original post with how I would like my model to be laid out! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without access to the Firebase Cloud Firestore collections, detailed in the link;

[Google Firebase Cloud Firestore Collections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#collections)

I achieved the result of grouping of my users by the following code, if anyone still wants to add an improved version please do, but for now this works as intended for me:

```
App {
    id: app

    property var groupName  
    property var subGroupName

//these values are assigned when my user logs in from user values
//set in firebase on registration


firebaseDb.getUserValue("group", {
                                }, function(success, key, value) {
                                if(success){
                                groupName = value
                                console.log("GROUPNAME LOG: " + groupName)}})
}
```

//I then use these values across my app when storing data in the database

//an example of which is an AppButton elsewhere in my app

```
    AppButton {
        id: saveButton                        
        onClicked: {
            userData = ({"date": calendar.selectedDate, "name": userName +" "+ userSurname, "details": dayCycle.text, "status": "pending"})
            var time = new Date().getTime()
            firebaseDb.setValue("groups" + "/" + groupName + "/" + subGroupName + "/" + time, userData)
    }
}
```